# How do I apply different headers to different pages using this template?

Tags: headers, conditional-tags

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="pagecontent-header">
        <?php the_title( '<span class="entry-title">', '</span>' ); ?>
        <p class="tagline"><?php the_field('tagline'); ?></p>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="container" style="padding: 50px 0px">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 generic_content text-center">
        <?php
            the_content();
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

The code above is my content-page.php. What conditional statement I can wrap the header around with so that I can use different headers by calling the pages thru their slugs? Thanks!

Comment: check [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

Answer (score 0):

// Create header-{SLUG}.php in theme folder and add this line in your header file

```
 global $post;
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    get_header($slug);
```

Comment: Please, format the code properly and add some explanation about what the code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: ok if you want to add diffrent header for test page ("test" is slug of that post) so when you call get_header($slug) in test page it's run like get_header(test);
and it means it's execute header-test.php instead of header.php from theme file.